# target Grid system disposition to landscape/portrait orientation with tablet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need the page to be responsive, On a bigger screen i need two columns and smaller screen I want 1 column, how can I do this ? Is there a class prefix like .col-sm-landscape- ou .col-sm-portrait- ^^ thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Following this doc : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_(2012), the nexus 7 has a resolution 1280 × 800 px.

Follwing this doc : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options :

> Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
>   Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
>   Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

So you may use :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6"> first column</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6"> second column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that should be `col-lg-6` instead of `col-ld-6`

Comment: this doesn't work I have always sm-12 in landscape and in orientation.... with my nexus 7